# How to add runnable OpenSSH server to an Ubuntu ISO?

Tags: software-installation, iso, squashfs

In order to create my own custom Linux ISO (Ubuntu), I have decompressed the Squash file system and would like to make the changes to leave it with a installed and working OpenSSH-Server before re-squashing it again to ISO.

I suppose these changes are:

- Some binary files in some specific directories.
- Some config files for the SSH Daemon.
- Some files corresponding to the keyfiles that are supposed to be generated.
- Some changes to the system files in order to make the SSH Daemon start on boot.

Sumarizing, I would like to change just the same that the classical `apt-get` installer would change.

If this is possible, how could it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you have the SSH keys and such in a specific defined SSH directory. It would be wise if you declared the path using `export` to the SSH binaries and keys directory. 
 In other words, you just have to have the daemon's startup script mapped to the boot file and the SSH path declared in the `.bashrc` file.